# Efficient storage of vectors for Java

Tags: library, java, serialization, data-structure

I'm writing an application in Java and would like to store the data. The data in question will be a certain number (may be a few 1000s) of vectors, and each vector would be of different size, but the bigger ones may be about 100000 elements long. A vector is composed of integers, doubles or strings (UTF-8).

I need to:

1. Read a few of those vectors as fast as possible when opening the application
2. Create new vectors as fast as possible
3. Modify the elements of a vector as fast as possible
4. Add or delete elements to a vector (anywhere on the vector) as fast as possible

So I would like a library to help me with that. I've already looked at:

- HDF5: while it seems to be what I want, I hated the APIs, everything seems to be overly complex, the documentation is not very good, the Java bindings seem to be a second class citizen and UTF-8 support seems not to be the default. In particular I am very afraid of [HDF5 Java limitations](https://www.hdfgroup.org/products/java/hdfview/UsersGuide/ug01introduction.html#ug01release).
- Java serialization: does not seem to have any way of modifying other than rewriting.
- Embedded databases: the ones I saw seemed to use SQL for which I have no use and would greatly complicate my very simple operations.

Comment: By “vector”, do you mean the [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)? I ask because that is an old class, not generally used since the advent of the [Java Collections framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html). Or do you mean just an array-like collection of values?

Comment: Is this for single-user single-threaded usage?

Comment: By vector I mean an array-like collection of values

Comment: it would be single use single thread